Where can I find the SQLite database of reactNative expo project?
I am using SQLite database in my reactNative expo android project. For debugging purposes, I need to get the database. So, I was searching for the database path, but I couldn't find the path.
I saw usually database will create inside the path /data/data/<package name>/database/. But there is no such folder with my app name in the data folder in my android studio manager device explorer.
Can anyone please help me to figure out where the location of the database?

Finally, I was able to figure it out myself. The file was located in the following location in my android studio manager device explorer,
/data/data/host.exp.exponent/files/SQLite/mydb

